# Managing Custom Designed Content

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, customization, themes

I designed a simple page that contains a styled image element and a styled paragraph of text underneath. The image and paragraph of text are related, so that one will never exist without the other. The number of these image-paragraph combinations on the page is unknown and will depend on the user, which will only be familiar with the admin panel, and will need to have the ability to create as many image-paragraph combinations as they need, when needed.

What would be the best way to allow this image-paragraph combination to be created, through the wordpress admin panel?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom post type and create metabox and make them dynamic, i.e like 
paragraph input    paragarph image input     Add more button.

This is the best way to achieve..

or a simple way would be register a custom post type and use its content as paragraph and featured image as paragraph image.

Thanks :)